# Are there any libraries for extracting class, method, member and field dependency names from a .class file (bytecode)?

Tags: java, scala, dependencies, bytecode, .class-file

As the title says, are there any libraries for extracting class, method, member and field dependency names from a .class file (bytecode)?

For example, if I a compiled Scala .class file uses something like this:

```
var xs = new List[java.lang.String]();
"blah" :: xs;
xs(0).charAt(0);
```

I should get that I use these classes and methods:

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.String#charAt
scala.collection.immutable.List
scala.collection.immutable.List#apply
```

Is there any library with API I can use in my own Scala program that can do this for me?

Comment: You might want to look at [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework [tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) explaining how to collect dependencies from classes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be able to read the code of method bodies. I would use a byte code library such as ObjectWeb's ASM, BCEL or JavaAssist.